# Error while inserting date and time in sql database table. I am getting error while trying to insert date and time in android studio sql database

Tags: javascript, android-studio, freesqldatabase

Mainly the application  I am buiding should be able to insert the title, description time and date the title is created. This is the database table I have created
for inserting title, content, date and time for an journal application.
While I was executing " the error as journal table column does not have a date " error occurred.

> 

```js
public class JournalDatabase extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "JOURNal_db";
    private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "Journal_table";
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    private static final String KEY_CONTENT = "content";
    private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";
    private static final String KEY_TIME= "time";




    public JournalDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String create = " CREATE TABLE "+DATABASE_TABLE+"("+KEY_ID+"INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"+
                KEY_TITLE+"TEXT,"+
                KEY_CONTENT+"TEXT,"+
                KEY_DATE+"TEXT,"+
                KEY_TIME+"TEXT" +")";
        Log.d("dbHarry","Query being run is : "+ create);
                db.execSQL(create);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        if (i >= i1)
            return;
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addJournal(Journal journal){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_TITLE,journal.getTitle());
        contentValues.put(KEY_CONTENT,journal.getContent());
        contentValues.put(KEY_DATE,journal.getDate());
        contentValues.put(KEY_TIME,journal.getTime());
        db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE,null,contentValues);
        db.close();
    }

    public Journal getJournal(long id){
        // select * from the databaseTable where id = 1
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE,new String[]{KEY_ID,KEY_TITLE,KEY_CONTENT,KEY_DATE,KEY_TIME},KEY_ID+"?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},null,null,null);
        if(null != cursor) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return new Journal(cursor.getLong(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4));
    }

    public List<Journal> getJournals(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        List<Journal> allJournals = new ArrayList<>();
        // SELECT * FROM DATABASE NAME
        String query = " SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE;
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Journal journal = new Journal();
                journal.setID(cursor.getLong(0));
                journal.setTitle(cursor.getString(1));
                journal.setContent(cursor.getString(2));
                journal.setDate(cursor.getString(3));
                journal.setTime(cursor.getString(4));

                allJournals.add(journal);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        return allJournals;
    }
}
```

> Blockquote
>
> Blockquote

[This is the screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8cRh.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to your log, there is no column named "date" in your table, check it please.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you Gaya Touak but I have column name date in journal database table but it is still showing the error. Can you see any error in Journal database table provided upright.